# Two div.textContent with same font, size and color are rendered differently in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I have 2 divs with the same text that are being rendered differently in Chrome.

The attached image is a screenshot of the two text elements at normal size and zoomed in, where the variance is much more obvious.

The only difference between the two elements is the top one is hardcoded in the HTML file as a `span` while the bottom one is programmatically generated as an `inline-block div` and appended at run time.  Programmatically generating both of them at runtime doesn't make them render the same, either.

Why is this happening and is it possible to have them render the same?

[image]

Both elements are styled with the font **[Muli-Semibold](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Muli)**, size `12`, color `#45B4E4`

```
@font-face {

    font-family: "Muli-Semibold";
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url("../../fonts/Muli-Semibold.woff2") format("woff2");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really related to your font, but rather because your elements don't have the same position.

What you see is called antialiasing, (or here *font smoothing*), and it is done in a way that the red, green, and blue dots of you screen will render the smallest line possible (so it looks smoother).

The algorithm will obviously output different smoothing values for where in the pixel coordinates you are. e.g., if everything fits perfectly on exact pixels, there wouldn't be any smoothing.

But with texts, you're almost never on a real pixel. For example, with your rules, I've got the first span with an width of `42.65625px` on my chrome. This means that the next inline element won't start on a finite pixel.

Here is an example showing that a block element, starting at the same x value will have the same correction as the original span, while the inline one will have an different correction.

```js
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.textContent = 'testing';
document.body.appendChild(d);
document.body.appendChild(d.cloneNode(1));
d.classList.add('inline')
```

```css
body{
    color: #45B4E4;
}
div.inline{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span>testing</span>
```

[image: screenshot of results]

And for a workaround... It's quite hard, because this can be caused either by the browser, or by the OS directly. Though, placing all your elements on rounded pixel coordinates might limit the differences.

Comment: I noticed that this wasn't happening in Firefox, only in Chrome.  I can't seem to recreate the problem by porting my code - [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/e94faurm/1/) is the closest I can share, but the problem is no longer visible, even when resizing the window (I'm using `vh` and `vw`) the font aliasing does not change.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 I'm not sure I do understand your comment. I could reproduce what you describe (on both FF and chrome btw). The font-smoothing will always occur, no matter the size of your window. The only thing you can try to do is to make both have the same correction, because they will both occupy the same x and y floating precision. But anyway, most of fonts are not pixel aligned, so you will always have antialiasing.

Comment: I believe there's some miscommunication here.  In my original screenshot, there is a difference between the antialiasing.  The top one contains other colors along with the text's blue color, while the bottom one only contains the text's blue color, even though it, too, is antialiased.  They are both antialiased, but they are rendered differently.  This affects the text's sharpness, as the bottom one appears to have a heavier weight and color, but it's the same as the one on top.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 and in my screenshot you can see that this occurs on the inlined element (the one at right) (because it's x precision is different than the span's one), while the block element produces almost the same antialiasing (because both its x and y precisions are the same).

Comment: Yes, I see how they differ slightly in your example, but they still have colored antialiasing so even though they are different, they will still appear quite similar.  However, the sub-pixel rendering of my two texts are different, as one contains additional colors while the other does not.  It's almost as if the antialiasing is being rendered as grayscale before the blue color is applied. [**Example here.**](http://i.imgur.com/JUDYICm.png)

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 and did you modified the `-webkit-font-smoothing` property ? Looks like it has been turned to `antialiased` instead of `subpixel-antialiased`.

Comment: I think it's caused by animations.  [**IN THIS EXAMPLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/e94faurm/2/) you can see the font weight looks much heavier and the color looks different while it's animating as opposed to when it stops animating.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 it's all possible that they chose an simpler smoothing algo for animated content ("perfs perfs perfs" seems to be the master word for chrome, even if quality has to be lost...)